# What is this attachment for on this veg peeler?

Tags: utensils

Just found a vegetable peeler with a very strange bladed attachment on the bottom of the handle.

The blades are all parallel but arranged in a V arrangement. There is an arrow pointing in the direction of the sharp edge of the blades and we can’t work out what it’s for.

Our best guess is a garlic slicer but then you’d end up with really big slices of garlic.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: A very tiny and limited Veg-O-Matic....

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Anything you want to make thin strips of. Green beans, carrots, something small enough to fit in there. You drag it through and it is split into thin slices.

[image]

This is an "action shot" from a [slightly more specialized version](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B075YPV76N) available on Amazon.

Comment: You can also use it to create a frilly effect for garnishing by pressing the item partway through, pulling it out and pushing it through again rotated 90 degrees. Best with celery, carrots, etc.